# How to parse a string to multiple types in c++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11

`cin >> *integerVar >> *charVar;` can read input like "25 b" correctly. What is the easiest way to do this with an existing string (I can do it manually by splitting and then parsing each part but what is the better way)?

Comment: `std::stringstream parser("My source string");` now you can use `parser` exactly the same way you use `cin`. Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: Why are you using pointers?  The C++ language is not C# or Java; you don't need to use the operator `new` for every variable or instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `istringstream` like, for example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::istringstream ss("25 b");
    int x; std::string bstr;

    ss >> x >> bstr;

    return 0;
}

// note that std:istringstream allows ss >> x, but not ss << "some value".
// if you want to support both reading and writing, use a stringstream (which would then support ss >> x as well as ss << "some value")
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use `istringstream` as a more specialized class?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think `istringstream` better expresses the intent if you only want to read, but `stringstream` will also work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: yes, that would be better; corrected the answer; thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6):

By using `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream myStr{"25 b"};
myStr >> *integerVar >> *charVar;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can utilize the [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (template) classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    int n;
    char c;
    ss >> n >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) which does the exact same thing as scanf but uses a string instead of STD input

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib>
#include<stdio>
int main(){
    std::string str;
    char character;
    int intnumber;
    cin >> str;
    sscanf (str.c_str(), "%d%c", &intnumber, &character);
}
```

Comment: Better give an example because this requires a bit of massaging of a `string` to work and `scanf` and friends are notoriously blind when it comes to being fed the wrong data types.

Comment: @user4581301 something like this ok?

Comment: Pretty close. Recommend using a  `std::string` in place of `char *`  for `str`, `char` instead of `char *` for `character`, and `sscanf (str.c_str(), "%d%c", &intnumber, &character);` on the call. because otherwise you are using some uninitialized pointers ( and an extra level of addressing on the call).

Comment: Right, I was actually trying to use the most basic c as possible. Thank you for your comments, tho

Comment: No worries, but note that this is a C++ question, not a C question. `stringstream` will catch all (or most) of the errors you can make with `sscanf` at compile time. `sscanf` will probably compile and do something weird when run, so its use is not recommended.